# How do I assign :ALELint to C-k in Vim?

Tags: vim

How I can assign `:ALELint` (A command of lint tool https://github.com/w0rp/ale) command to normal mode C-k in vim?
(

I tried `nnoremap C-k :ALELint`, But it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's

```
nnoremap <C-k> :ALELint<CR>
```

The `<` `>` are required for making vim parse the contents as a key code. The `<CR>` at the end represents pressing <kbd>Return</kbd>.

Comment: See `:h key-codes` for more information on key notation (the `<c-k>` business)